# Utilizing multi core for tar+gzip/bzip compression/decompression

Tags: gzip, tar, bzip2, bzip

I normally compress using `tar zcvf` and decompress using `tar zxvf` (using gzip due to habit).

I've recently gotten a quad core CPU with hyperthreading, so I have 8 logical cores, and I notice that many of the cores are unused during compression/decompression.

Is there any way I can utilize the unused cores to make it faster?

Comment: The solution proposed by Xiong Chiamiov above works beautifully. I had just backed up my laptop with .tar.bz2 and it took 132 minutes using only one cpu thread. Then I compiled and installed tar from source: https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/ I included the options mentioned in the configure step: ./configure --with-gzip=pigz --with-bzip2=lbzip2 --with-lzip=plzip I ran the backup again and it took only 32 minutes. That's better than 4X improvement! I watched the system monitor and it kept all 4 cpus (8 threads) flatlined at 100% the whole time. THAT is the best solution.

Answer (score 413, accepted):

You can use [pigz](http://zlib.net/pigz/) instead of gzip, which does gzip compression on multiple cores.  Instead of using the -z option, you would pipe it through pigz:

```
tar cf - paths-to-archive | pigz > archive.tar.gz
```

By default, pigz uses the number of available cores, or eight if it could not query that.  You can ask for more with -p n, e.g. -p 32.  pigz has the same options as gzip, so you can request better compression with -9.  E.g.

```
tar cf - paths-to-archive | pigz -9 -p 32 > archive.tar.gz
```

Comment: How do you use pigz to decompress in the same fashion? Or does it only work for compression?

Comment: pigz does use multiple cores for decompression, but only with limited improvement over a single core.  The deflate format does not lend itself to parallel decompression.  The decompression portion must be done serially.  The other cores for pigz decompression are used for reading, writing, and calculating the CRC.  When compressing on the other hand, pigz gets close to a factor of _n_ improvement with _n_ cores.

Comment: The hyphen here is stdout (see [this page](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41828/what-does-dash-at-the-end-of-a-command-mean)).

Comment: So as far as I understand files generated by pigz are compatible with gzip right? Can I decompress a file with gzip which had been created with pigz?

Comment: Yes.  100% compatible in both directions.

Comment: pigz can use multiple cores for compression, but the tar operation is still using only one core. Is there a parallel tar?

Comment: There is effectively no CPU time spent tarring, so it wouldn't help much.  The tar format is just a copy of the input file with header blocks in between files.

Comment: I have submitted an edit to the answer to indicate the default number of compression thread to be equal to the number of online processors as per official docs but not to the 8 cores as was specified in the answer originally. Thanks.

Comment: The edit seems to have been rejected by someone else, but I will make a similar edit.

Comment: just drop the -f option of tar if you want stdout. ;-)

Comment: Beware that redirecting (`>`) will simply overwrite existing files unless you have `set -o noclobber` set.

Comment: Also worth noting that since pigz probably is going to be network-bound in most situations unless you make it work hard, increasing the block size can dramatically improve performance. By increasing its block size to 524288 (512MB), I'm seeing numbers as high as 80MB/s over 802.11ac wifi. I believe the transfer is still network-bound, so you may see better results over gigabit ethernet.

I sometimes see insane 400MB/s spikes, but those are scary and odd, so I'm not sure what to make of them.

Comment: @WilliamTFroggard The spikes may be due to the burstiness of the deflate algorithm. Uncompressed data is collected until a deflate block can be produced, at which time the block is rapidly generated and emitted.

Comment: Wouldn't be more performatic to use `-l` instead of STDIN/STDOUT?

Comment: I wouldn't know, since "performatic" is not a word.

Comment: This is actually faster than `tar -c --use-compress-program=pigz`

Answer (score 459):

You can also use the tar flag `--use-compress-program=` to tell tar what compression program to use.

For example use:

```bash
tar -c --use-compress-program=pigz -f tar.file dir_to_zip
```

Comment: This is an awesome little nugget of knowledge and deserves more upvotes. I had no idea this option even existed and I've read the man page a few times over the years.

Comment: @ValerioSchiavoni: Not here, I get full load on all 4 cores (Ubuntu 15.04 'Vivid').

Comment: I prefer `tar - dir_to_zip | pv | pigz > tar.file`
pv helps me estimate, you can skip it. But still it easier to write and remember.

Comment: @NathanS.Watson-Haigh Yes do you. Just enclose the program name and arguments in quotes. `man tar` says so, as does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51275570/3258851).

Comment: In 2020, `zstd` is the fastest tool to do this. Noticeable speedup while compressing and decompressing. Use `tar -cf --use-compress-program=zstdmt` to do so with multi-threading.

Comment: Confirmed. on a 32-core Threadripper Pro, compressing 3.6GB LJSpeech dataset via zstd needs less than half the time than pigz:

`real 0m3.219s <=>  real 0m6.570s`

Answer (score 145):

### Common approach

There is option for `tar` program:

```
-I, --use-compress-program PROG
      filter through PROG (must accept -d)
```

You can use multithread version of archiver or compressor utility.

Most popular multithread archivers are [pigz](http://www.zlib.net/pigz/) (instead of gzip) and [pbzip2](http://compression.ca/pbzip2/) (instead of bzip2). For instance:

```
$ tar -I pbzip2 -cf OUTPUT_FILE.tar.bz2 paths_to_archive
$ tar --use-compress-program=pigz -cf OUTPUT_FILE.tar.gz paths_to_archive
```

Archiver must accept -d. If your replacement utility hasn't this parameter and/or you need specify additional parameters, then use pipes (add parameters if necessary):

```
$ tar cf - paths_to_archive | pbzip2 > OUTPUT_FILE.tar.gz
$ tar cf - paths_to_archive | pigz > OUTPUT_FILE.tar.gz
```

Input and output of singlethread and multithread are compatible. You can compress using multithread version and decompress using singlethread version and vice versa.

#### p7zip

For p7zip for compression you need a small shell script like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
case $1 in
  -d) 7za -txz -si -so e;;
   *) 7za -txz -si -so a .;;
esac 2>/dev/null
```

Save it as 7zhelper.sh. Here the example of usage:

```
$ tar -I 7zhelper.sh -cf OUTPUT_FILE.tar.7z paths_to_archive
$ tar -I 7zhelper.sh -xf OUTPUT_FILE.tar.7z
```

#### xz

Regarding multithreaded XZ support. If you are running version 5.2.0 or above of XZ Utils, you can utilize multiple cores for compression by setting `-T` or `--threads` to an appropriate value via the environmental variable XZ_DEFAULTS (e.g. `XZ_DEFAULTS="-T 0"`).

This is a fragment of man for 5.1.0alpha version:

> Multithreaded  compression and decompression are not implemented yet, so this
>   option has no effect for now.

However this will not work for decompression of files that haven't also 
been compressed with threading enabled. From man for version 5.2.2:

> Threaded decompression hasn't been implemented yet.  It will only work
>   on files that  contain  multiple  blocks  with size  information  in
>   block headers.  All files compressed in multi-threaded mode meet this
>   condition, but files compressed in single-threaded mode don't even if
>   --block-size=size is used.

### Recompiling with replacement

If you build tar from sources, then you can recompile with parameters

```
--with-gzip=pigz
--with-bzip2=lbzip2
--with-lzip=plzip
```

After recompiling tar with these options you can check the output of tar's help:

```
$ tar --help | grep "lbzip2\|plzip\|pigz"
  -j, --bzip2                filter the archive through lbzip2
      --lzip                 filter the archive through plzip
  -z, --gzip, --gunzip, --ungzip   filter the archive through pigz
```

Comment: This is indeed the best answer. I'll definitely rebuild my tar!

Comment: I just found [pbzip2](http://compression.ca/pbzip2/) and [mpibzip2](http://compression.ca/mpibzip2/). mpibzip2 looks very promising for clusters or if you have a laptop and a multicore desktop computer for instance.

Comment: This is a great and elaborate answer. It may be good to mention that multithreaded compression (e.g. with `pigz`) is only enabled when it reads from the file. Processing STDIN may in fact be slower.

Comment: Plus 1 for `xz` option. It the simplest, yet effective approach.

Comment: `export XZ_DEFAULTS="-T 0"` before calling `tar` with option `-J` for xz compression works like a charm.

Comment: This answer looks like it was largely lifted directly from my [LQ post](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/utilizing-multi-core-for-tar-gzip-bzip-compression-decompression-4175426075/#post5040938). A link back might have ben nice.

Comment: thank you SIR for the `xz` thing. made my day!

Answer (score 14):

You can use the shortcut `-I` for tar's `--use-compress-program` switch, and invoke `pbzip2` for bzip2 compression on multiple cores:

```
tar -I pbzip2 -cf OUTPUT_FILE.tar.bz2 DIRECTORY_TO_COMPRESS/
```

Comment: A nice TL;DR for  @MaximSuslov's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27541309/1593077).

Comment: This returns `tar: home/cc/ziptest: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors`
`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have more flexibility with filenames and compression options, you can use:

```
find /my/path/ -type f -name "*.sql" -o -name "*.log" -exec \
tar -P --transform='s@/my/path/@@g' -cf - {} + | \
pigz -9 -p 4 > myarchive.tar.gz
```

#### Step 1: `find`

`find /my/path/ -type f -name "*.sql" -o -name "*.log" -exec`

This command will look for the files you want to archive, in this case `/my/path/*.sql` and `/my/path/*.log`. Add as many `-o -name "pattern"` as you want.

`-exec` will execute the next command using the results of `find`: `tar`

#### Step 2: `tar`

`tar -P --transform='s@/my/path/@@g' -cf - {} +`

`--transform` is a simple string replacement parameter. It will strip the path of the files from the archive so the tarball's root becomes the current directory when extracting. Note that you can't use `-C` option to change directory as you'll lose benefits of `find`: all files of the directory would be included.

`-P` tells `tar` to use absolute paths, so it doesn't trigger the warning "Removing leading `/' from member names". Leading '/' with be removed by `--transform` anyway.

`-cf -` tells `tar` to use the tarball name we'll specify later

`{} +` uses everyfiles that `find` found previously

#### Step 3: `pigz`

`pigz -9 -p 4`

Use as many parameters as you want.
In this case `-9` is the compression level and `-p 4` is the number of cores dedicated to compression.
If you run this on a heavy loaded webserver, you probably don't want to use all available cores.

#### Step 4: archive name

`> myarchive.tar.gz`

Finally.

Answer (score 2):

A relatively newer (de)compression tool you might want to consider is [zstandard](https://github.com/facebook/zstd). It does an excellent job of utilizing spare cores, and it has made some great trade-offs when it comes to compression ratio vs. (de)compression time. It is also highly tweak-able depending on your compression ratio needs.

Comment: I added an example how to use Zstd with tar here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75483439/315168

Answer (score 2):

You can speed up decompression by using a multi-threaded gzip decoder like [rapidgzip](https://github.com/mxmlnkn/indexed_bzip2/tree/master/python/rapidgzip). You can use it with tar like this:

```bash
python3 -m pip install --user rapidgzip
tar -x --use-compress-program=rapidgzip -f archive.tar
```

With a Ryzen 3900X 12-core processor, it can easily achieve a 12x speedup for simple gzip decompression, not accounting for GNU tar. These are the results for a 4 GiB large file (compressed size: 3.1 GiB):

| Decoder | Runtime / s | Bandwidth / (MB/s) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| rapidgzip -P 24 | 1.320 | **3254** |
| rapidgzip -P 1 | 8.811 | 487 |
| igzip -T 24 | 9.295 | 462 |
| igzip | 9.225 | 466 |
| bgzip -@ 24 | 15.962 | 269 |
| bgzip | 16.202 | 265 |
| pigz | 13.391 | 321 |
| gzip | 22.218 | 193 |

[igzip](https://github.com/intel/isa-l/tree/master/igzip) is a good alternative as well. It can be installed with: `sudo apt install isal`. Just as pigz, it cannot arbitrarily parallelize decompression but, just as bgzip and pigz, it can parallelize compression with the `--threads` option.

A second alternative would be `bgzip`, which can be installed with: `sudo apt install tabix`.
Although `bgzip` cannot parallelize decompression of arbitrary gzip files, it can parallelize decompression for files compressed with bgzip, see e.g. these benchmarks for the same file as above but compressed with bgzip:

| Decoder | Runtime / s | Bandwidth / (MB/s) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| rapidgzip -P 24 | 1.125 | **3818** |
| rapidgzip -P 1 | 7.520 | 571 |
| igzip -T 24 | 7.377 | 582 |
| igzip | 7.321 | 587 |
| bgzip -@ 24 | 1.949 | **2204** |
| bgzip | 10.621 | 404 |
| pigz | 18.466 | 233 |
| gzip | 21.346 | 201 |

The code for the benchmarks can be found [here](https://github.com/madler/pigz/issues/36#issuecomment-1159322302).

Comment: I tried to use rapidgzip for compression, but not work. Decompression works fine. Any reason why?

Comment: @StayFoolish It wasn't intended for compression. Parallel compression of gzip is a solved problem. You can use pigz or bgzip for that. However, parallel decompression of any gzip file only works with rapidgzip. I understand the desire to use rapidgzip as a drop-in-replacement for gzip, so I might add compression in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for `tar` with modern `zstd` compressor, as finding out good examples on this one was difficult:

- Do recursive and directiores (`zstd` standalone cannot do this)
- `apt` poem to install `zstd` and `pv` utilities for Ubuntu
- Compress multiple files and folders (zstd command alone can only do single files)
- Display progress using `pv` - shows the total bytes compressed and compression speed GB/sec real-time
- Use all physical cores with `-T0`
- Set compression level higher than the default with `-8`
- Display the resulting wall clock and CPU time used after the operation is finished using `time`

```bash
apt install zstd pv
DATA_DIR=/path/to/my/folder/to/compress
TARGET=/path/to/my/arcive.tar.zst

time (cd $DATA_DIR && tar -cf - * | pv  | zstd -T0 -8 -o $TARGET)
```