# docker run --cpuset is not having any effect

Tags: docker, cpu-usage, multicore, resource-management, cpuset

I started one docker container by specifying the cpuset to 1 cores:

```
docker run --cpuset-cpus="0"...
```

A second one by specifying the cpuset to 4 cores:

```
docker run --cpuset-cpus="0-3"...
```

I launched a load process within each container and I monitored the cpu consumption for both containers.

The load process is like:

```
ffmpeg input > output
```

I have observed that there is no improvement in term of execution time between both containers (no speed up).

Do you have any idea why there is no improvements? container with 4 cores should run faster than 1 core container right ?

NB: 
using top for 1core container

```
CPU0%=100%
CPU1%=0
CPU2%=0
CPU3%=0
```

using top for 4core container, docker chooses randomly one of 4 cores to launch the process. Sometimes it affects 30% for each core

```
CPU0%=0                  CPU0%=30%                   CPU0%=0
CPU1%=100%       or      CPU0%=30%            or     CPU0%=0
CPU2%=0                  CPU0%=30%                   CPU0%=0
CPU3%=0                  CPU0%=30%                   CPU0%=100%
```

Answer (score 9):

`gzip` does not use multiple cores even if they are available. As a result this program is not well suited to do performance tests regarding the use of CPU cores.

Use [pzip](http://zlib.net/pigz/) instead. see [Utilizing multi core for tar+gzip/bzip compression/decompression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313242/utilizing-multi-core-for-targzip-bzip-compression-decompression)

Also see [How can I produce high CPU load on a Linux server?](https://superuser.com/questions/443406/how-can-i-produce-high-cpu-load-on-a-linux-server)

---

conveniently the `stress` tool is already available on the Docker Hub, so you can verify that the docker [`--cpuset-cpus`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#cpuset-constraint) option is working correctly by running:

```
docker run --rm -it --cpuset-cpus="0-3" jess/stress --cpu 4
```

→ you will witness that all 4 cores go to 100% usage.

then by running:

```
docker run --rm -it --cpuset-cpus="0-1" jess/stress --cpu 4
```

→ you will witness that just 2 cores go to 100% usage.

Comment: for ffmpeg library it is the same thing... how can I optimize the cpu consumption to use 100% of each core in multicore system?
`ffmpeg input.avi ouput.mp3`

Comment: this is another question.

Comment: the problem is that I don't want to use the stress tool provided by Docker Hub. I want to stress C libraries like ffmpeg with 100% for each core.

Comment: and that is a very specific case which merits it own question. A quick search in google will show you that the ffmpeg process can or cannot use multiple threads depending on the codec you specify for the encoding. So you should ask a question regarding the specific use of ffmpeg and the codec you plan to use