# How to use Pigz with Tar

Tags: bash, tar

So I am using pigz in tar with

```
tar --use-compress-program=pigz
```

and this works but it doesn't use all of my processors, and I'd like to make sure it's recursive (-r) and using (-9 compression level).

I read through [Utilizing multi core for tar+gzip/bzip compression/decompression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313242/utilizing-multi-core-for-targzip-bzip-compression-decompression) but it doesn't note anywhere to add additional commands in that format, and I couldn't find anything in the man page for either program for additional swithed.

Thanks,
Cam

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Utilizing multi core for tar+gzip/bzip compression/decompression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313242/utilizing-multi-core-for-targzip-bzip-compression-decompression)

Comment: AFAIK gzip level 9 is not a good choice, as it takes much more CPU times without much benefit. YMMV, but as compared to level 4 you have 3 times more CPU time for about 1% file size difference. Also, xz level 1 has less calculations than gz level 9 with better rates.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Mark Adler's top voted answer on the SO link that you included in your question does provide a solution for specifying compression-level as well as number of processors to use:

```
tar cf - paths-to-archive | pigz -9 -p 32 > archive.tar.gz
```

See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320421

Answer (score 52):

To pass arguments to `pigz` using `-I` or `--use-compress-program`, you can [enclose the command and arguments in quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/gzip.html), like so:

```
tar --use-compress-program="pigz --best --recursive" -cf archive.tar.gz YourData
```

Here's a fun option to monitor the speed of the archive creation:

```
tar --use-compress-program="pigz --best --recursive | pv" -cf archive.tar.gz YourData
```

Comment: Can this command be used like this, `tar --use-compress-program="pigz -dc -p 20" -xvpf test.tgz -C /home/test_dir`? I tried, but it **failed**. I  want to decompress my tgz file under number of custom threads.

Comment: pigz cannot parallelise decompression, according to the man page [1], but does split out reading, writing, and checking into separate threads so is at least a bit faster than gzip.

[1] https://linux.die.net/man/1/pigz

Answer (score 37):

fast unpack:

```
tar -I pigz -xf /mnt/sd/current/backup/bigbackup_web.tar.gz -C /tmp
```

fast pack:

```
tar -cf bigbackup.tar.gz -I pigz /opt
```

then:

```
apt-get install pigz
```

or

```
yum install pigz
```

or for MacOS with Homebrew

```
brew install pigz
```

Comment: The argument `--use-compress-program=pigz` in the OP is the same as `-I pigz`.

Comment: Can we speed up the unpacking process? As far as i know, compressing doesn't need any extra arguments and pigz uses every core. But when i unpack it, it doesn't seem to be using all cpu...

Comment: This does not answer the question.