# How to use tar + pbzip2 with Jenkins

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, tar, bzip2

I've been trying to find ways to cut my Jenkins build time as much as possible, and thanks to this helpful SO post, I found pbzip2: [Utilizing multi core for tar+gzip/bzip compression/decompression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313242/utilizing-multi-core-for-targzip-bzip-compression-decompression)

Works great! A 6 min compression time was brought down to 2 mins on my machine with the following:

`tar -v -c --use-compress-program=pbzip2 -f parallel.tar.bzip2 myapplication.app`

But Jenkins just barfs with a Execute Shell task where I put in the above command:

`+ tar -v -c --use-compress-program=pbzip2 -f parallel.tar.bz2 myapplication.app
a myapplication.appBuild step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure`

The fact that the "Build step" line is getting mashed together with the output from the tar tells me it might be a **background process issue** that tar/pbzip2 is introducing.

I've tried introducing a `#!/bin/bash -xe` and get the same results. I've tried wrapping the tar command in an if statement. I've also tried putting tar in a background thread itself with `&` and waiting for it. Same result.

Is there any techniques I could implement to help the Jenkins process out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that even though I can run this command as the jenkins user through command line, pbzip2 wasn't defined in the PATH for the Jenkins job. Pretty misleading since there wasn't useful output.

Comment: this is interesting but how did you resolve it in the PATH? Where do you put it?